# Wavelength and PCB trace

Tags: pcb, rf, ac

I was thinking of ac signals recently and I am trying to visualize wavelength of an AC signal. If I take a 30KHz signal, the wavelength of this is 10Km which is a super long distance. Can someone tell me how this wave will travel in a standard wire or a trace (of say 10cm)?

I can understand that the signal cycles 30,000 times in a second but I am not able to visualize how it would travel say 10cm. I am sure I am thinking this all wrong and would like some inputs on it.

Thanks

Comment: Do you understand how dc travels 10 cm in a wire?

Comment: At 30 kHz one wave is 10 km, you need 3 GHz for one wave to fit in 10 cm. So if you look at 10 cm but the wave is 10km you're only  seeing the first 1/100000th part of the wave. So in practice, you don't see that wave travelling, it is there instantaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Finite velocity effects

When an electromagnetic wave propagates, it does at a *finite velocity*. This is evident when the distance covered is comparable to the wavelength.

In what way it reveals? Along the section considered, the field variations are observed.

When the distance is much smaller than the wavelength, the finite velocity of propagation does not matter. The effect of the disturbance fields, is "instant" for all points of the section considered.

Taking the example that you propose, for a wave of 30 kHz, the wavelength is 10 km. This means that at 10 km, you can measure the field variation as a function of distance because it is evident that the wave does not spread instantly.
For a length of 10 cm, the effect of the field is observed "instantaneously" at all points.

Answer (score 2):

If you pick a single point on the trace, the wave will travel "up" and "down" at 30KHz

[image]

You don't need to think of the wavelength at all if you picture your receiver as a single point in space, with the signals amplitude oscillating about that point.

Comment: This answers what I was looking for. I guess if I want to visualize the variation of a signal along distance I need a surface plot. Thank you for the answer